# MathNet.Symbolics Algebraic.Expand in descending order?

Tags: c#, math.net, mathnet-numerics, mathdotnet-symbolics

With `MathNet.Symbolics` library, I try to print a polynomial with a descending power order:

```
using mse = MathNet.Symbolics.Expression;
using MathNet.Symbolics;

public void Symbolics()
{
    var x1 = 2;
    var y2 = 3;
    var x2 = 4;

    // (2a+3)(a-4)

    var x = mse.Symbol("x");
    var a = mse.Symbol("x");
    var y = mse.Symbol("y");

    var expression = (x1 * a + y2) * (a - x2);
    var expanded = Algebraic.Expand(expression);
    var firstResult = Infix.Format(expanded);


    Debug.Log("Expression: " + expression);
    Debug.Log("Expanded: " + firstResult);
}
```

The current output is in ascending order: `-12 - 5*x + 2*x^2`, but I want it the other way. 
I tried `.ToStringDescending()` function, in polynomials but was unable to get it working here.

Also, output to Latex would be useful if possible but not essential.

How do I have have the result of `Algebraic.Expand` in descending not ascending order?

Comment: What is `mse`  ?

Comment: Sorry mse is: using mse = MathNet.Symbolics.Expression; (have updated question code to include this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have Latex output with the corresponding format provider:

```
Console.WriteLine("LaTeX.Format: " + LaTeX.Format(expanded));
```

The best I can get is to use `Summands` to get them and the reverse the list. Sadly the `+` sign is lost in the process:

```
Console.WriteLine("Summands: " + string.Join("+", Algebraic.Summands(expanded).Reverse().Select(Infix.Format)));
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help here! The LaTex tip is really useful and the Summands use may well end up being how I have to do it, if so I will come back and mark this as answered.

Comment: Marked as the answer as from reading elsewhere this may very well be the only/best way to do this and perhaps some Regex could reinstall that +...as a result will be looking for a MathNet alternative

Answer (score 0):

Numerics.Polynomial has ToString() that returns the string in ascending form and

ToStringDescending(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
Format the polynomial in descending order, e.g. "x^3 + 2.0x^2 - 4.3"

that returns the string in descending form.

Comment: Thank you phv, however quoting the initial question: "I tried `.ToStringDescending()` function, in polynomials but was unable to get it working here." How are you converting from symbolics expressions to numerics polynomials? I instead wrote this: `string.Join(" ", StringYouWantReversing.Split(' ').Reverse());`  after being inspired by @Orace